# How to commence the dragging of a UIImage using UIDraginInteraction?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to drag an UIImage using UIDragInteraction.  I am trying to implement the procedure as documented in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drag_source).  My code is below.  I am trying to perform the drag feature but currently my image is not moving even when i hold the left mouse button on the image and try to drag it (I have yet to implement the Drop implementation as i am trying to do this one step at a time).  I am executing the code on a simulator.

my code:

```
class StartGameViewController: UIViewController{

var dragInteraction: UIDragInteraction!
var dragInteractionDelegate: UIDragInteractionDelegate!


var dragSourceImgView: UIImageView = {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    imgView.contentMode = UIImageView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
    return imgView
}()
var dropImgSourceView: UIImageView = {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = UIImageView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    return imgView
}()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dragSourceImgView.image = UIImage.init(named: "rider")
    let frame = CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    dragSourceImgView.frame = frame
    container1.addSubview(dragSourceImgView)

    let frameDrop = CGRect.init(x: 200, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    dropImgSourceView.frame = frameDrop
    container1.addSubview(dropImgSourceView)


    // Enable imageView as a drag source
    dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction.init(delegate: self)
    dragSourceImgView.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
}
}


// DRAG
extension StartGameViewController: UIDragInteractionDelegate{

// Create a Drag Item
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {

    guard let image = dragSourceImgView.image else{return []}
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider.init(object: image)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem.init(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    return [dragItem]
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set your `UIImageView` to allow user interaction:

```swift
dragSourceImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

If you are running on an iPhone you must also set the `UIDragInteraction` to be enabled:

```swift
dragInteraction.isEnabled = true
```